# How to compute the 4 X 4 homogeneous transformation matrix for an image in python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, homogenous-transformation

I have an image and I want to obatain the homogeneous transformation matrix of that Image in python. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQUZI.jpg).
Can someone please help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "the homogeneous transformation matrix of an image".  I think the quality of your question would be improved by either explicitly describing what you are trying to compute, or at least providing a link with a relevant definition.

Comment: sorry for the abstract question. I have very minimal knowledge about it, still in learning phase. Here is the link I referred to: [link](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node111.html). Thank you. @Quaternion

Answer (score 1):

A translation matrix (a transformation matrix for translation) is of the form -

```
[[1, 0, 0, tx],
 [0, 1, 0, ty],
 [0, 0, 1, tz],
 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

You could use [`imutils`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) library which has convenient implementations of these transformations or refer to the official `opencv` [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I got the concept you are telling. My problem is that, I have an image for which I have to compute Homogenous matrix. The image matrix is of size 570 x 720. How do I get the TRANSLATION MATRIX you specified above. I have done similar to this by matching feature points from 2 images. But I don't know how to do with single image. It would be great if you can give me some pointer to do.

Comment: A homogenous matrix for an image? What do you mean by that? Please specify what you are trying to do. Are you saying you would like to do shift an image in a window?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found an another way instead of  computing  homogenous matrix. Can you please tell me a way to decompose a projection matrix into corresponding rotation and translation matrices. Thank you one again :@parthagar

Comment: Please give an example of projection matrix and corresponding rotation and translation matrices.

Comment: The Projetion matrix is as follows:
[[8.77557038e+02  3.68758099e+02  1.00770594e+03 -3.02599230e+02]
[-2.67151813e+02  1.02679339e+03  3.85585808e+02 -1.97845102e+02]
[-7.77710773e-02  1.39598852e-01  9.87149340e-01 -8.22007766e-01]]

Comment: The Projection matrix is as follows:

$$ 
    \begin{matrix}
   8.77557038e+02&3.68758099e+02&1.00770594e+03&-3.02599230e+02\\
   -2.67151813e+02& 1.02679339e+03&3.85585808e+02&-1.97845102e+02\\
    7.77710773e-02&1.39598852e-01&9.87149340e-01&-8.22007766e-01\\
    \end{bmatrix}

The Rotation Matrix is:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.97070342&0.23639364&0.04304553\\
   -0.22734672&0.96157694&-0.15389367\\
   -0.07777108&0.13959885&0.98714934\\
    \end{bmatrix}

The Translation matrix is : $$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.51029554\\
0.25278783\\
-0.82200777\end{bmatrix}

Thank you.

Comment: I tried my best to give in correct format of matrices. Somehow it didnot work. Sorry for poor notation: @parthagar

Comment: Try to use composite matrices as defined at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix.